# Blank avplayer layer and no sound

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerlayer

After several (depends on device - 2-3 transitions on first SE, more than 20 transitions on 11) transitions between two vc in navigation stack (from custom camera vc to custom video player vc) I get blank player layer without any playing video or sound. I checked up memory graph and don't found any leaks. play(), seek() and other methods don't works. I tried to change player layer frame directly in this case but it has right values. Unfortunately there is unpredictable trouble inside custom player. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.